# Display out of stock product only for specific Category in Magento2

Tags: magento2, category, layered-navigation, out-of-stock

I have to show out of stock products only in certain categories by hiding them in all other categories.

used below plugin to implement, that is not working.

**Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer">
    <plugin name="Vendor_Module_Layer" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\CatalogInventoryLayer" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"  />
</type>
```

Then

**Vendor/Module/Plugin/CatalogInventoryLayer.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer as CatalogLayer;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection as ProductCollection;

class CatalogInventoryLayer {
protected $_logger;
public function __construct( 
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ){
        $this->_logger = $logger;
    }
public function aroundPrepareProductCollection(CatalogLayer $subject, \Closure $proceed, $collection)
{
    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/customlog.log');
    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);        
    $categoryId = $subject->getCurrentCategory()->getId();      
    $proceed($collection);
    if ($categoryId == 4){
        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                 ['_inventory_table' => 'cataloginventory_stock_item'], 
                 "_inventory_table.product_id = e.entity_id", ['is_in_stock']
        );
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('is_in_stock',array('eq'=>'0'));

    }       

    return $this;
    }
  }
```

**Update:**

**Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\CatalogInventory\Helper\Stock">
  <plugin name="Vendor_Extension_Stock_Helper" type="Vendor\Extension\Plugin\Helper\Stock" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"  />
</type>
```

**Vendor/Module/Plugin/Helper/Stock.php**

```
<?php 
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Helper;
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\ResourceModel\Stock\StatusFactory;
class Stock
{    
private $logger;
protected $_registry;
protected $request;
protected $stockStatusResource;
protected $stockStatusFactory;
public function __construct(
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
    StatusFactory $stockStatusFactory
) {
    $this->logger = $logger;
    $this->_registry = $registry;
    $this->request = $request;
    $this->stockStatusFactory  = $stockStatusFactory;
}
public function aroundAddIsInStockFilterToCollection(\Magento\CatalogInventory\Helper\Stock $subject, \Closure $proceed, $collection)
{
    try{
        $category = $this->_registry->registry('current_category');//get current category
        $currentPage = $this->request->getFullActionName(); //catalogsearch_result_index
        if(!is_null($category) && $currentPage!= 'catalogsearch_result_index')
        {
            $stockFlag = 'has_stock_status_filter';
            $categoryId = $category->getId();                   
            $parentCategoryId =  $category->getParentCategory()->getId();               
            if($categoryId == 10 || $parentCategoryId == 10)
            {
            $resource = $this->getStockStatusResource();                
                $resource->addStockDataToCollection(
                        $collection,
                        false
                ); 
            }
            $collection->setFlag($stockFlag, true);
        } 
        return $this;
    }catch(\Exception $e){
        return $e->getMessage();
        $this->logger->info('--exception--'.$e->getMessage());
    }
}

public function getStockStatusResource(){
    if (empty($this->stockStatusResource)) {
        $this->stockStatusResource = $this->stockStatusFactory->create();
    }
    return $this->stockStatusResource;
   }
}
```

I have to display them only when we visit some specific categories by hiding them in all other categories

The updated code is working in category page, but search result page out of stock from other categories also visible,

**Is there any way to show only out of stock products which belongs to category id '10'.**

Can anyone please check and update me if there is any other way to implement the above functionality. Thanks!!

Comment: What's your magento version?

Comment: @RohanHapani, its 2.3.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do above things, you need to do this things.

> 1. Vendor\Extension\etc\di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\CatalogInventory\Helper\Stock">
    <plugin name="Vendor_Extension_Stock_Helper" type="Vendor\Extension\Plugin\Helper\Stock" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"  />
</type>
```

2. Create the Helper File with arround plugin.

> Vendor\Extension\Plugin\Helper\Stock.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Plugin\Helper;

class Stock
{    
    public function aroundAddIsInStockFilterToCollection(\Magento\CatalogInventory\Helper\Stock $subject, \Closure $proceed, $collection)
    {
       // Do your Logic Here
        return $returnValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: hi @Dhiren, this has issue with the count in layer navigation

Comment: but the search result page still out of stock products showing for all.

Comment: @Manjunath have you sorted out the count layered navigation issue?

Answer (score 2):

You should extend the original function ( Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\ProductCollectionStockCondition::apply() ) which is checking the stock configuration.

"Display out of stock products" config in store > Config > catalog > inventory.

You can use preference to extend that apply() function and add additional condition like that.

```
from:
$this->stockHelper->addIsInStockFilterToCollection($collection);

to:
if(in_array(category_id, ur_list_of_ids))
$this->stockHelper->addIsInStockFilterToCollection($collection);
```

In this way, you can enable out of stock products in some of the category only.

Comment: it is not so clear, can you update me  as answer please, I have to set Display out of stock products as "yes" in admin?

Comment: yes, you have to set it as "yes" and extend the original class file which is adding filter based on your config. you can add your category condition in your extended class.

Comment: if set to yes, the out of stock products will display in all the cats, how can we avoid that

Comment: could you update me working code please..

Comment: @Manjunath - I dont have working code now. but given the suggestion based on my previous experience.

Answer (score 1):

You can display `**ONLY Out Of Stock products for particular category page**`, first, you need to set configuration for Display Out of Stock Products, `Go to Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory > Stock Options->Display Out of Stock Products` set as `Yes`, because for category page and product page product is not visible or not in collection if it's set as No, I'm not sure why Out Of Stock products is not available in Collection without "Display Out of Stock Products" configuration.

But for display Out Of Stock products for a particular category, you can change `aroundPrepareProductCollection()` as per below or replace your plugin file, I have checked it displays only Out Of Stock product only on the Category page.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer as CatalogLayer;

class CatalogInventoryLayer
{
    public function aroundPrepareProductCollection(CatalogLayer $subject, \Closure $proceed, $collection)
    {
        $categoryId = $subject->getCurrentCategory()->getId();
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/OutOfStock_Product.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);

        //Get Out Of Stock Products
        $collection->addFieldToSelect('*')
            ->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', true)
            ->joinField('stock_item', 'cataloginventory_stock_item', 'is_in_stock', 'product_id=entity_id', 'is_in_stock=0');
        $collection->addCategoriesFilter(['eq' => $categoryId]); // Current category filter, it's not require, because PrepareProductCollection() automatically apply filter for current category. 

        $logger->info(print_r($collection->getData(), true));

        return $collection;
    }
}
```

Out of stock products of Bags category, you can see in screenshots.

[image]

[image]

I hope it will helpful for you.

Comment: hi @rohit, thanks for the answer, but where u are checking the condition in your answer for particular category? I think u missed it, pls double check once

Comment: this is not working, getting exception Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.min_price' in 'field list',

Comment: Hello @Manjunath, No, I have not missed, because category filter is not require here, because PrepareProductCollection() is call for current category page, and in "vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Layer.php" file you can check "prepareProductCollection()" function, we just need to pass collection, it'll automatically apply CURRENT CATEGORY FILTER, I have tested above code it's working fine.

Comment: "vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Layer.php"
 public function prepareProductCollection($collection)
   {
        $this->collectionFilter->filter($collection, $this->getCurrentCategory());

        return $this;
    }

If you still apply filter then please check my updated answer.

Comment: Hello @jafarpinjar, I have tested above code, it's working fine for me.

Comment: @Rohit, lets suppose my category id is 20, I have to show only oos products in that category, in your code there is no condition to check, so it applies on all categories

Comment: You can use addCategoriesFilter().

Comment: Did you checked "prepareProductCollection" function of default Magento in ""vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Layer.php" file?

Comment: We have used "prepareProductCollection" function in our plugin, so in default "prepareProductCollection" category filter will automatically apply, we no need to pass that filter, please check "prepareProductCollection" function of core Magento.

Comment: @Rohit, possible to update screenshots for me, one category with showing oos products other without oos products, I am worried if used like above, that's fire for all categories, where is the condition we are checking to show oos products only in that category

Comment: @Rohit, (RuntimeException): Illegal state error i am getting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104867/discussion-between-manjunath-and-rohit).

Comment: @Rohit, are you able to see out of stock product only in specific category?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using magento 2.4 then you have to create a plugin for

> Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer

We have to set the Go to Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory > Stock Options->Display Out of Stock Products. This is necessary because Magento doesn't load the is_in_stock filters when we set this option to 'NO'. So we can't put our custom work/conditions when it sets to NO I've debugged it completely and well , So first we have to set it to YES , then I've created a plugin for Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer`and I've handled in such a way that it is now working properly.
1- The Out Of Stock and In Stock products will be shown for specified category
2- Other all the categories of the store will only show InStock products according to our requirement.

The code is below:

```
public function aroundPrepareProductCollection(CatalogLayer $subject, \Closure $proceed, $collection)
{
    // Getting current category Id
    $categoryId = $subject->getCurrentCategory()->getId();
    // Getting specified category whom we wann show OOS products
    $showAllCategoryId = $this->displayBoth->getShowAllCategoryId();

    if($categoryId == $showAllCategoryId) {
        //Get Out Of Stock Products and also In Stock Products of the specified category
        $collection->addFieldToSelect('*')
            ->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', true)
            ->joinField('stock_item', 'cataloginventory_stock_item', 'is_in_stock', 'product_id=entity_id',
                'is_in_stock=0 || is_in_stock=1');
        // Apply to the collection
        $collection->addCategoriesFilter(['eq' => $categoryId]); // Current category filter, it's not require, because PrepareProductCollection() automatically apply filter for current category.
    }else{
        //Get only In Stock products to the all the categories instead of above specified one
        $collection->addFieldToSelect('*')
            ->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', true)
            ->joinField('stock_item', 'cataloginventory_stock_item', 'is_in_stock', 'product_id=entity_id',
                'is_in_stock=1');
        //Apply to the collection
        $collection->addCategoriesFilter(['eq' => $categoryId]);
    }
    return $proceed($collection);
}
```

This has been tested well and working fine for Magento 2.4 EE and CE

Comment: can you share with me complete code of this file ?